# How can I improve the accuracy of Math.atan()?

Tags: javascript, math

I was trying to do some comparison between the angles of points, but quickly I ran into some strange results.

In this example I try rotate lines so that they point to the center, but the lines seem to angle more than they should quite quickly. Then, right above and below the center the lines start to point in all sorts of directions [(These values are beyond the mathematical range of atan(x))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=atan(x)).

How can I get accurate results from Math.atan()? Is there an alternative method to do this calculation?

I uploaded a 'working' version to this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0y2p6p3n/. I am working in Chrome.

html:

```
  <div id="content">                
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
let points = [];
let amount = 1000;
let width = 300;
let height = 300;

for (let i = 0; i<amount;i++) {
    let x = Math.random(); 
    let y = Math.random();
    let point = {x, y};
    points.push(point);
    points[i].tan = Math.atan(0.5 - points[i].y)/(0.5 - points[i].x);
    points[i].error = Math.abs(points[i].tan) > 3.14/2 ? true : false;
}   
for (let point of points) {
    let line = document.createElement("div");
    line.classList.add("line");
    line.style.marginTop = point.y*height + "px";
    line.style.marginLeft = point.x*width + "px";
    line.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + ((point.tan*(180/Math.PI))) + "deg)";
    point.error == true && line.classList.add("error");

    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(line);
}
```

css:

```
#content {
    position: relative;
}
.line {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}
.error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using

```
points[i].tan = Math.atan(0.5 - points[i].y)/(0.5 - points[i].x);
```

It should be

```
points[i].tan = Math.atan( (0.5 - points[i].y)/(0.5 - points[i].x) );
```

```js
let points = [];
let amount = 1000;
let width = 300;
let height = 300;
for (let i = 0; i<amount;i++) {
  let x = Math.random(); 
  let y = Math.random();
  let point = {x, y};
  points.push(point);
  points[i].tan = Math.atan( (0.5 - points[i].y)/(0.5 - points[i].x) );
  points[i].error = Math.abs(points[i].tan) > 3.14/2 ? true : false;
} 
for (let point of points) {
  let line = document.createElement("div");
  line.classList.add("line");
  line.style.marginTop = point.y*height + "px";
  line.style.marginLeft = point.x*width + "px";
  line.style.transform = "rotateZ(" + ((point.tan*(180/Math.PI))) + "deg)";
  point.error == true && line.classList.add("error");
  document.getElementById("content").appendChild(line);
}
```

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned, the exact asymptotes (i.e. pi/2 and -pi/2) are outside of the valid domain of `atan`, which makes taking the `atan` of those values impossible.  You also may have to deal with the fact that atan always returns a reference angle, which may not be the quadrant you want your answer to be in.  These are very well known issues, and most languages have a simple cure, called atan2.  In the case of javascript, please see [the MDN reference for atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).

The change to your code is simple; simply change

```
points[i].tan = Math.atan(0.5 - points[i].y)/(0.5 - points[i].x);
```

to

```
points[i].tan = Math.atan2(0.5 - points[i].y, 0.5 - points[i].x);
```

If you check out the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y2p6p3n/1/), you may see its behavior has improved considerably.

atan2 doesn't give you higher precision, but it does give you values over the complete range of [0..2pi], without you having to do all the extra work of figuring out which quadrant the answer should be in, as well as supporting pi/2 and -pi/2 within its range.  It is helped in doing so by knowing whether the x or the y (or both) is negative, a fact which gets hidden if you do the division yourself.

It should be noted that the most significant change I made to your code was not atan2, however, it was changing around your use of parenthesis.  While I'm an advocate for using atan2 any time you would normally use atan, your actual issue was misuse of parenthesis, making Oriol's answer the right one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The way I understand it is that atan2() allows for improved precision because the 2 parameters aren't compressed into 1, as they are when dividing them to fit them into atan().

Comment: `atan` does not behave oddly near the asymptotes.

Comment: @Oriol True.  It's simply undefined at the asymptotes.  I'll change that.  More importantly, I should have noticed when I was doing my fix that the issue in this case was simply misuse of `atan`.